# Best way to design and parallelize a Spark application in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am developing a spark application in Scala and would like to know the best approach to parallelize it and run on Hadoop cluster.  My code would read each line from HDFS file parse it and generate multiple records(for each line) which I am storing as a case class.I have written the complete logic in getElem() method and working as expected.

Now, I would like to compute the logic for all the input records and store the response to  HDFS location.

Please let me know how would I deal this with spark and consolidate all the corresponding output records generated for the input and write to HDFS.

```
        object testing extends Serializable {
      var recordArray=Array[Record]();
       def main(args:Array[String])
      {

      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("jsonParsing").setMaster("local")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val sqlContext= new SQLContext(sc)

      val input=sc.textFile("hdfs://loc/data.txt")
     // input.collect().foreach(println)
      input.map(data=>getElem(parse(data,false),sc,sqlContext))

    }
          //method definition
    def getElem(json:JValue)={

         // Parses the json and creates array of datasets for each input record and stores the data in case class
  val x= Record("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx")
             }
  case class Record(summary_key: String, key: String,array_name_position:Int,Parent_Level_1:String,Parent_level_2:String,Parent_Level_3:String,Parent_level_4:String,Parent_level_5:String,
        param_name_position:Integer,Array_name:String,paramname:String,paramvalue:String)
           }
```

Comment: The code example is incomplete.  `recordArray` is never used, `getElem` doesn't specify a return type (and in the code you posted it just returns `Unit`). It also has the wrong signature, you pass a `SparkContext` and `SQLContext` to it in your map but in the definition it only accepts `JValue`.  `parse` is never explained.  Could you please post a working example that shows your problem and point out exactly what about it isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You said you have working `case class` and that you have `parsed` the `input text file` from `hdfs` and coverted to the `record case class`. 
Then converting to `dataframe` or `dataset` would be easy by using `.toDF()` or `.toDS()` 
Now the task left is just to write the `case class rdd` or `dataframe` or `dataset` to `hdfs`
 
**To write case class rdd to hdfs :**
just call `.saveAsTextFile()` api and you can give the path to `output directory` as you gave to read from `hdfs`
**To write dataframe or dataset to hdfs :**
you can use `databricks` api `.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save()` where you can give output hdfs dir name

I hope this helps

**Note:** I guess you are running the codes through `ide`. You should learn to `spark-submit` more info can be found at [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am running it through IDE. I don't want to dump the records to HDFS after every single input row is processed, that way it creates many part files. I would like to process all the input records and then dump the output to HDFS. But, with my above code the getElem method is never getting invoked

Comment: With the above code, it's not even getting to the point it could run getElem as it will not compile. Fix your question, we can't guess what code you're actually running - but it's certainly not what's in your question

Comment: @sun_dare, **you will have to update your question with your parse method so that I can test it and post you the complete answer**. And by the way you can use `coalesce` to get single output. And you have to learn about [transformation and action](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-rdd-transformations.html) so that you understand how spark works.